# jQuery toggleClass with multiple sections within an accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have a problem where I'm trying to accomplish a change in the body background-color when I click a specific section of an accordion.

It goes as follows: 
I have three sections within one accordion. 
When I click on section #1 I want the body background-color to change.
When I click on section #2 I want the body background-color to switch back to the original background-color and then change to the new one thats tied to section #2, and same goes on section #3 and so forth.

I have accomplished this with toggleClass when clicking between the diffrent sections, and it works all fine. But the problem comes when I click on the same section twice in a row. The background-color switches back to the original body background-color but then it comes back into the if-statement and activates the toggleClass once again, so the background switches to the section #1 background.

I want it to work like when clicking on the same section twice the original body background-color should stay as active.

Are there any simple solution to this? (I guess it is...)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
 $('.accordion').on('click', function() {
  $('body').removeClass('webbutveckling-1-body-background webbutveckling-2-body-background granssnittsdesign-body-background', 1000);
  if($(this).is('.accordion-section-webbutveckling-1')){
   $('body').toggleClass('webbutveckling-1-body-background', 1000);
   
  } else if($(this).is('.accordion-section-webbutveckling-2')){
   $('body').toggleClass('webbutveckling-2-body-background', 1000);
   
  } else if($(this).is('.accordion-section-granssnittsdesign')){
   $('body').toggleClass('granssnittsdesign-body-background', 1000);
  }
 });
  
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #e68246;
}
/*----- Accordion -----*/
.accordion, .accordion * {
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box; 
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
 
.accordion {
    overflow:hidden;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    border-radius:3px;
    background:#f7f7f7;
}
 
/*----- Section Titles -----*/
.accordion-section-title {
    width:100%;
    padding:15px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-bottom:1px solid #1a1a1a;
    background:#666;
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
    /* Type */
    font-size:1.200em;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #1a1a1a;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
 
.accordion-section-title.active, .accordion-section-title:hover {
    background:#4c4c4c;
    /* Type */
}
 
.accordion-section:last-child .accordion-section-title {
    border-bottom:none;
}
 
/*----- Section Content -----*/
.accordion-section-content {
    padding:15px;
    display:none;
}

/*----- Accordion heading -----*/
.accordion-section-content-heading {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #cdcdcd;
}

/*----- Accordion ul-tasks -----*/
.accordion-ul-tasks {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.accordion-ul-tasks li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.accordion-ul-tasks a {
    display: block;
    color: #787;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    
    transition: margin-left .4s;
}

.accordion-ul-tasks a:hover {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.accordion-ul-tasks a:before {
    content: "> ";
}

.accordion-ul-tasks li:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
}

/*----- Accordion Toggle Classes for body background -----*/
.webbutveckling-1-body-background {
    background-color: #46aae6;
}

.webbutveckling-2-body-background {
    background-color: red;
}

.granssnittsdesign-body-background {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <main class="main-content">
                <section class="accordion accordion-section-webbutveckling-1">
                    <section class="accordion-section">
                        <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-1">Webbutveckling 1</a>
                         
                        <section id="accordion-1" class="accordion-section-content">
                            <h2 class="accordion-section-content-heading">Introduktion</h2>
                            <ul class="accordion-ul-tasks">
                                <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Länk till skolverket - Webbteknik</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Google Drive - Skapa ett konto</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Loggbok: Elevmall</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </section> <!--end .accordion-section-content-->
                    </section> <!--end .accordion-section-->
                </section> <!--end .accordion-->
                
                <section class="accordion accordion-section-webbutveckling-2">
                    <section class="accordion-section">
                        <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-2">Webbutveckling 2</a>
                         
                        <section id="accordion-2" class="accordion-section-content">
                            <p>Mauris interdum fringilla augue vitae tincidunt. Curabitur vitae tortor id eros euismod ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
                        </section> <!--end .accordion-section-content-->
                    </section> <!--end .accordion-section-->
                </section> <!--end .accordion-->
                
                <section class="accordion accordion-section-granssnittsdesign">
                    <section class="accordion-section">
                        <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-3">Gränssnittsdesign</a>
                         
                        <section id="accordion-3" class="accordion-section-content">
                            <p>Mauris interdum fringilla augue vitae tincidunt. Curabitur vitae tortor id eros euismod ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
                        </section> <!--end .accordion-section-content-->
                    </section> <!--end .accordion-section-->
                </section> <!--end .accordion-->
            </main>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a working snippet?

Comment: Of course. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.accordion').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).is('.accordion-section-webbutveckling-1')){
        $('body').removeClass('webbutveckling-2-body-background granssnittsdesign-body-background', 1000);
        if(!$('body').hasClass('webbutveckling-1-body-background'))
            $('body').addClass('webbutveckling-1-body-background', 1000);

    } else if($(this).is('.accordion-section-webbutveckling-2')){
        $('body').removeClass('webbutveckling-1-body-background granssnittsdesign-body-background', 1000);
        if(!$('body').hasClass('webbutveckling-2-body-background'))
            $('body').addClass('webbutveckling-2-body-background', 1000);

    } else if($(this).is('.accordion-section-granssnittsdesign')){
        $('body').removeClass('webbutveckling-1-body-background webbutveckling-2-body-background', 1000);
        if(!$('body').hasClass('granssnittsdesign-body-background'))
            $('body').addClass('granssnittsdesign-body-background', 1000);
    }
});

});
```

The problem is, that you have to avoid removing and adding the class of the section again after you clicked it twice, else you will have a fade out and in.
Hope that helps :)

Comment: Amazing mate. Works like a charm.

Comment: Got a question about improving the script tho... Can I make it only change between the section backgrounds when clicking on diffrent sections of the accordion and ONLY change back to the standard body background-color when clicking a section twice?

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help :)

Comment: you could just replace the the lines of the if's, so like:
`if(!$('body').hasClass('granssnittsdesign-body-background'))
            $('body').addClass('granssnittsdesign-body-background', 1000);`

completely to

`$('body').toggleClass('granssnittsdesign-body-background', 1000);`, so you just toggle the class on and off, and all other classes will be removed

Comment: Yeah it all works changing between the diffrent sections now and they are all switching to the correct colors, but. When I click between the sections the original body background-color always comes first and then the correct section color appears. I don't want the original background-color to appear when only clicking through the various sections except when clicking the same section twice, then the original background-color should appear. Does this make any sense? ;)

Comment: This is my code now, one for each section: 

`if($(this).is('.accordion-section-webbutveckling-1')){
   $('body').removeClass('webbutveckling-2-body-background granssnittsdesign-body-background', 1000);
   $('body').toggleClass('webbutveckling-1-body-background', 1000);
    
  }`

Comment: Ahm you could swap the order, so first apply/toggle the class and the remove the others, because it will remove all, fall back to the original one AND THEN apply the new color. :)

Comment: But I think you could also remove the translationtimer from the removeClass-Part, else with would fade off without a point.